# What is the meaning of "مُوَلِّي"?

Tags: quran, arabic, definitions

The word مُوَلِّي appears in Quran verse 2:148. 
I have read a few translations of the verse 
(e.g. [here](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=2&verse=148)) but 
I still don't have a good understanding of what the *word* means.
I looked it up on [المعاني](http://www.almaany.com) but it is not there.

What is the meaning of the word?

I am not looking for the translations of the verse, I know them. 
I am trying to understand the verse better by understanding 
the meaning and the usage of the word in Arabic.

Answer (score 3):

I found a text in the site www.mahdi313.ir which could be profitable for you. In accordance with its Tafseer, **the meaning of مولی  could be a Qiblah, or a direction, which is related to a leader or Imam (as the right direction)**

Of course I found some sites in Farsi which are related to your question, (if you know Farsi), you can see them. They are as shown in below (as sources).

---

**Sources:**

- [www.mahdi313.ir](http://www.mahdi313.ir/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1368:----148--&catid=66:1389-10-11-11-02-58&Itemid=88)
- [www.porseshkadeh.com](http://www.porseshkadeh.com/Question/13529/)
- [www.yasmedia.ir](http://yasmedia.ir/1391/11/23/gharaati-tafsire-soore-baghare31-aye-148-rahhaye-be-sooye-hagh.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to translate this word in English. I can nearly say **مولی** is a subject that means a person who stand in a special direction
و لکل وجهه هو مولیها
means any direction has some people who stand in.

Answer (score 2):

Well the مُوَلِّي is a noun (from the family) of the verb وَلَّى which may have many meanings like elapse (if the context is time), follow (if it's about a person or an authority) or assign or direct, turn, turn away ... as you can find here:

[http://www.almaany.com](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D9%88%D9%84%D9%89/)

In the context of the Verse only turn/turn away are acceptable.

This would mean that مُوَلِّي is a person which turns to a certain direction or turns away from a certain direction.